# Duplicate text with multiple large text-shadows in Safari

Tags: css, browser, fonts, safari

I'm experiencing a weird font rendering problem when using multiple large text-shadows in Safari 9.1.1. The text and the shadows render fine, but it looks like part of the text is being duplicated about 110px below the original text.

Here's an example of the issue (must be viewed in Safari):

```css
h3 {
  text-shadow: 0 0 40px #000, 0 0 80px #000;
}
```

```html
<h3>
Testing multiple text-shadows
</h3>
```

The position of the duplicate text is somewhere around 110px below the real text, and starts appearing when the second shadow has a spread of 60 to 70px.

The attributes of the first shadow, and the opacity and position of the second shadow don't have any effect. Only the font-size and spread of the second shadow seem to make any difference.

The only way I have been able to get rid of it is to remove or reduce the text-shadow.

I have also been able to get the text to duplicate a second time if I add a third large text-shadow.

Has anyone seen this before? Anyone have a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've seen the same bug when creating a complex data visualization with D3.js. We could only fix it by removing the second `text-shadow`. There's a [bug reported for Webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=111216) that seems very related, but there's been no progress on it.

Answer (score 1):

After a little bit of experimentation, it appears to be related to the blur radius value of the text shadow.

For your particular case, if you change it to

`h3 {
  text-shadow: 0 0 40px #000, 0 0 60px #000;
}`

The text artifact in Safari should disappear. You will have both shadows, but the blur won't be as large, so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `text-shadow: 0 0 40px #000;`

Look at the fixed code: https://jsfiddle.net/yp9jatLw/2/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that defeats the purpose. I'm trying to use 2 text-shadows. Your solution just omits one of them.